# What RPC technology can I use to call a compiled assembly (rather than my own class) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, soap, rpc, json-rpc

I want to access a .NET compiled assembly through RPC (the calling code is Python but that is not really relevant).

The assembly represents an API to a running third-party application (Autodesk AutoCAD, for example). It contains several namespaces which contain static classes which contain API objects. I need to access all kinds of stuff in that object hierarchy: properties, objects, methods and, perhaps most complex, transactions that use IDisposable interface (that essentially means that state, i.e. objects storage, should be maintained between RPC calls).

Rather than continuing to develop my own solution (which uses ZeroMQ messaging and reflection-based call dispatch), I wonder what RPC technology would suit my needs.

I looked into basic examples of popular libraries that implement JSON-RPC and SOAP. I see that these libraries demand that you inherit your callable class from their base classes and put attributes into class declaration, for example

```
[SoapMethod("RequestResponseMethod")]
```

in order for RPC to work. Obviously, I cannot do that in the case of an external pre-compiled assembly.

I would like to know if JSONRPC or SOAP are indeed the wrong choice for the task that I described or there actually is a way to make RPC work with an external assembly that I don't know about.

Any guidance, comments or basic advice would be much appreciated since I have no experience using any of the existing RPC technologies.

Comment: host it as a windows service?

Comment: I'm not sure how this will provide a solution to the problem. Care to share any references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about JSON / SOAP I guess you are using HTTP, which is stateless => you need to supply some kind of "state variable". This can be done via e.g. a cookie or like in my examle:

To access your external API create a "wrapper service" (using WCF or "old-school web-services"):

```
public class MyApiAccess : IMyApiService
{
    private static Dictionary<int, MyAPI> apiInstances = new Dictionary<int, MyAPI>();

    public int StartSession()
    {
        var api = new MyAPI();
        int id = api.Id; // or some other way to get an unique id
        apiInstances.Add(id, api);
        return id;
    }
    public void EndSession(int sessionId)
    {
        // ensure "sessionId" is valid
        var api = apiInstances[sessionId];
        api.Dispose();
        apiInstances.Remove(api);
    }

    public MyType MyMethod(myParameter param)
    {
        // ensure "sessionId" is valid
        var api = apiInstances[sessionId];
        return api.MyMethod(param);
    }
}
```

This should give you a starting point how such a service could be implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am using web sockets right now and researching an option to use HTTP. The transport doesn't really matter a lot at this point.
The wrapper service looks like something I would try to avoid because that would mean I need to wrap every property and method in the target API that I want to call, if I read your example right.

Comment: `The wrapper service looks like something I would try to avoid because that would mean I need to wrap every property and method in the target API that I want to call, if I read your example right.` yes you are right, but IMO there is no way around that, if you are using an external API...

Comment: Well, the current way I do this involves reflection. in the receiving code, I have a dictionary of static classes that I want to be able to call. I then invoke a call to the external API by parsing the string that was in the incoming RPC message. That way I can avoid writing wrappers.

Comment: Yes, that "works", but for something static this sounds more like a "hack" to me, not a performant solution. You could also do this here by implementing a generic `public object InvokeMethod(string methodName, object param)` method...

Comment: If I keep that part of my solution, I don't really need SOAP or JSONRPC because I basically still implement my own RPC. That's the gist of the question: switch to a well-developed library or stick to my own solution.

Comment: That's my concern too but the external API is absolutely huge and may involve other software with further respective APIs, there's no way I could be able to write wrappers for all that. Either way, your answers were very helpful, thanks!

Comment: `switch to a well-developed library or stick to my own solution` that you need to answer for yourself. More work, but performant and maintainable or "quick and dirty"? If anyway possible I would always choose the former...

Comment: ...also you could "mix it": Implement the "base API" as "full blown wrappers" and leave the option via reflection for the rest...

Comment: Last one: what exactly do you find hackish, the overall use of reflection or parsing generally arbitrary request for what seems to be a finite, sorta enumerable set of objects? Like, some sort of code generation (for wrappers) would be the better way to go?

Comment: IMO: Refelction is if you do not know what you need to call at compile time, but you do here as you already have the static API you want to call => "hackish" or at least "shortcut with side-effects"...

Comment: ...also think of your customers / users: A "full blown wrapper" also has a defined structure (i.e. WSDL) which is VERY usefull for users of that service.

Comment: Thanks, I will use this to decide on the better option.